# How do I debug a Maven project in VS Code?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to write Java, with the Maven build plugin. It's going fine after a lot of fiddling with configuration, except for debugging. The debug configuration looks something like this:

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-App<music-03>",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "ptcs.App",
        "projectName": "music-03"
    }
```

When I launch the debugger with the second configuration, debugging my project app (not launching the current file), I get an error:

```
~/Sync/projects/music/music-03:cd /Users/Mike/Sync/projects/music/music-03 ; /Library
/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:58363 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/var/folders/pn/3p41p2fj14d50n707c7x2p4c0000gn
/T/cp_90sfb6m3zinsbhwyvyknqb5hv.argfile ptcs.App 

Error: Could not find or load main class
@.var.folders.pn.3p41p2fj14d50n707c7x2p4c0000gn.T.cp_90sfb6m3zinsbhwyvyknqb5hv.argfile
```

Note that I have no trouble running the maven compile and package goals, and I even can produce an executable jar packaged with dependencies. My pom.xml is a bit long to reproduce here, but if anyone can give me a hint what I should post from it, I will do so.

Comment: Why is ` "mainClass": "${file}"` pointing to a file name instead of a classname?

Comment: I don't use that one (the config for launching a single file). I presume that it's intended for situations in which there is one file with one public class, and by Java requirements the base file name and the class name are the same.

Comment: The problem here is that there is an assumption that "@...." has special meaning to the jvm (probably containing some additional arguments) which it hasn't so it is interpreted as the class name (because that is what the JVM expects next).  The "pcts.App" is then not interpreted as the classname but would have been the first entry in the arguments passed into the main method.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that's not me running that command .. it's VS Code. So the problem is.. why did VS Code try to run java that way and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to add the package name with the mainClass like `"mainClass": "com.my.test.App",`

Comment: `ptcs` is the package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. The @ symbol in the command-line only works for Java 1.9 and higher, and the Java debugger plugin is mistakenly putting that in its command line.

One solution is to update the project to a higher version of Java. Another solution is to add `shortenCommandLine : jarManifest` to launch.json. A third possibility is to point $JAVA_HOME to your JDK location and restart VS Code.

Comment: I used the second solution - `"shortenCommandLine": "jarmanifest"` added to the run project template